# Sign my .NET dll to verify it is my plugin? 

Tags: c#, plugins, dll, code-signing

I have domain app and plugins for it. Is there good solution to sign my dll's with some key to verify plugin in my app?

Thanks for all

Comment: Just using strong-names doesn't cut it (e.g. have the app maintain a list of "safe" plug-ins -- this is how ASP.NET works with "safe controls")? Even if you don't load from the GAC, you can still inspect the SN/evidence of the assembly.

Comment: @pst Thanks for response, all i want thats to check is it my plugin or not.

Comment: may be [how-to-forbid-a-net-dll-class-library-to-be-referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323339/how-to-forbid-a-net-dll-class-library-to-be-referenced) helps

Answer (score 2):

If you're the only one that is going to do plugins for the application it is a good solution of course, but if you want others to do them you would have to share that key and then you're losing its control.

Comment: Thanks for response, all i want thats to check is it my plugin or not.

Comment: Then signing is the best option. When you load your plugin you have to check if the dll public key is the same as yours.